# Updating records requires a valid InsertCommand when passed DataRow collection with new rows

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to add data from a form back into an Access table but I keep getting this error message:

> Update requires a valid InsertCommand when passed DataRow collection
> with new rows.

And for the life of me I can't work out what I need to do.

Here's the code for the button click that's supposed to update the records.

```
Public Class Orders

    Dim ClientOrderConnection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

    Dim Provider As String
    Dim dbSource As String
    Dim sqlQuery As String

    Dim dsClientOrder As New DataSet
    Dim daClientOrder As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dtOrders As New Data.DataTable
    Dim Booking As New ArrayList



    Dim RowNumber As Integer
    Dim Counter As Integer = 0
    Dim NumberOfRows As Integer

    Private Sub Orders_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load



        Provider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
        dbSource = "Data Source = A2ComputingDatabase.accdb"

        ClientOrderConnection.ConnectionString = Provider & dbSource

        ClientOrderConnection.Open()

        sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM TblClientOrder"

        daClientOrder = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlQuery, ClientOrderConnection)

        daClientOrder.Fill(dsClientOrder, "ClientOrder")

        ClientOrderConnection.Close()

        NumberOfRows = dsClientOrder.Tables("ClientOrder").Rows.Count


    Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click



        If RowNumber <> -1 Then

            Dim cbClientOrder As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder
            Dim dsClientNewRow As DataRow




            dsClientNewRow = dsClientOrder.Tables("ClientOrder").NewRow()

            dsClientNewRow.Item("ClientOrderNumber") = txtOrderNo.Text
            dsClientNewRow.Item("ClientTelNo") = txtClientTelNo.Text

            dsClientOrder.Tables("ClientOrder").Rows.Add(dsClientNewRow)

            daClientOrder.Update(dsClientOrder, "ClientOrder")


            MsgBox("New Reocrd added to the Database")
        End If



    End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have to instantiate the OledbCommandBuilder from your DataAdapter:

```
cbClientOrder = New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(daClientOrder)
```

Dim cbClientOrder with your DataAdapter then put that somewhere after the daClientOrder.Fill() call and you should be good to go. And of course get rid of the other declaration of cbClientOrder in your btnSubmit_Click event.